# Can anybody help me for the syntax of select query?

Tags: c#, sql

i`m doing

```
string sql = "select * from publisher where title like "'"+tbproperty.text+";
```

but it`s not working!

regards..

Comment: What happens - how does it fail?

Comment: For info, you are missing an end quote after the literal, but as most of the answers and comments tell you; **use a parameter**.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(VS.71).aspx):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from publisher where title like @title");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", tbProperty.Text);
```

If you need to add more to the parameter, then do the following (E.g.: output parameter):

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@param ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

This means you don't need to build the string per se and stops SQL injection.

Comment: +1 wish I could +10000 your answer!! Always always always (and no exceptions) use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 4):

With `LIKE`, if you expect begin/ends matches you need some wildcards such as `'%'`, and I'm *assuming* that the user isn't adding those; but - **important**: [don't concatenate user input](http://xkcd.com/327/). Ever; you want something like:

```
sql = "select * from publisher where title like @arg";
```

With `@arg` defined as a parameter, with value something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arg", "%" + tbproperty.text + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction..

```
string sql = "select * from publisher where title like '" + tbproperty.text + "'";
```

Comment: hey listen.. i have my function in my class but the tbproperty does not show in my class.. ?? how do i do it ??

Comment: @Azka - only you know where `tbproperty` exists; if you are doing your data access separate to the UI (which you should) then you'll have to pass the desired title in as a parameter to your method.

Comment: i have my search publisher function in my class publisher and it is :
public int searchpublisher()
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from publisher where title like @title");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", but here in the object value, the tbproperty does not exist in the intellisence.. 


}

Comment: You can modify the metod in your Publisher class as follows:

public int searchpublisher(string title) 
{  
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from publisher where title like @title");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
}

Then call that method from the appropriate place in the UI (i.e. where you have access to the textbox) and call it like this:

int publisher = searchpublisher(tbproperty.Text);